# Python – 'type' error in the function header

Tags: python, debugging

My Python assignment requires the following function header:

`def choose(self, options:list[str]) -> str:`

But when I try using this in a program, even if the body just returns simple text like `return "string"`, then I get the error message:

```
def choose(self, options: list[str]) -> str:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Did you mean: `List[str]`?

Comment: `list[str]` is only available syntax in python 3.9, you're probably using an earlier version of python in which case @quamrana is correct

Comment: @quamrana if I use `List[str]` then it says that `NameError: name 'List' is not defined`

Comment: Ok, but you need to look at the linked duplicate question.